# Concatenate strings using ## operators in C

Tags: c, concatenation, string-concatenation, c-strings, preprocessor-directive

In C we can use ## to concatenate two arguments of a parameterized macro like so:

> `arg1` ## `arg2` which returns `arg1arg2`

I wrote this code hoping that it would concatenate and return me a string literal but I cannot get it to work:

```
#define catstr(x, y) x##y

puts("catting these strings\t" catstr(lmao, elephant));
```

returns the following error:

```
define_directives.c:31:39: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘lmaoelephant’
   31 |         puts("catting these strings\t" catstr(lmao, elephant));
      |                                       ^
      |                                       )
```

It seems the strings are concatenating but they need to be wrapped around quotes in order for `puts` to print it. But doing so, the macro no longer works. How do  I get around this?

Comment: You need to convert the arguments `lmao` and `elephant` to string literals somewhere along the line.  That might be the `#` operator after you've concatenated the symbols to create `lmaoelephant` with the `##` operator.  Or you might simply need to convert the arguments to strings — that will be easier.  `#define catstr(x, y) #x #y` would work with `puts("concatenating these strings; " catstr(lmao, elephant));` and would yield `concatenating these strings: lmaoelephant` on a single line of output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use the call to `puts()` in this way, the macro `catstr()` should be constructed to do two things:

- stringify and concatenate `lmao` to the string `"catting these strings\t"`
- stringify and concatenate `elephant` to `lmao`.

You can accomplish this by changing your existing macro definition from:

```
#define catstr(x, y) x##y
```

To:

```
#define catstr(x, y) #x#y
```

This essentially result in:

```
"catting these strings\t"#lmao#elephant
```

Or:

```
"catting these strings   lmaoelephant"
```

Making it a single null terminated string, and suitable as an argument to `puts()`:

```
puts("catting these strings\t" catstr(lmao, elephant));
```

Answer (score 5):

You do not need to use `##` to concatenate strings. C already concatenates adjacent strings: `"abc" "def"` will become `"abcdef"`.

If you want `lmao` and `elephant` to become strings (without putting them in quotes yourself for some reason), you need to use the stringize operator, `#`:

```
#define string(x) #x

puts("catting these strings\t" string(lmao) string(elephant));
```